# Im trying to find this button and there is a seperate one for each player. Is there a code i can use to call upon each player which is interchangeable

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is an example of 2 of the players HTML source

[image: 1st Player's HTML source]

[image: 2nd Player's HTML source]

Using python and selenium. If you are able to give me a code to find one of the elements i can probably find a way to change it for any given player. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the link to that page?

Comment: https://fantasy5.com/football/player-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this **xpath** index like this :

```
(//span[@class='player-name'])[1]
```

or for button :

```
//div[contains(@class, 'add-remove-player')]//button[contains(@class,'StyledIconButton')]
```

this will represent all of them.

and if you are looking for first one :

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'add-remove-player')]//button[contains(@class,'StyledIconButton')])[1]
```

2nd will be :

```
(//div[contains(@class, 'add-remove-player')]//button[contains(@class,'StyledIconButton')])[2]
```

and so on..

in code :-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'add-remove-player')]//button[contains(@class,'StyledIconButton')])[1]").click()
```

and so on for other buttons.